# Powershell can't invoke .net class' method

Tags: powershell

I wrote powershell script which contains this code: 
`foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines ...`
It works fine on my pc but fails on another one (the same .net framework version) with error:
**Method invocation failed because [System.IO.File] doesn't contain a method named 'ReadLines'.** What's wrong?

Comment: First example says ReadLine... your error says `ReadLines` with an S.  Is that a typo or the cause ?

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger sorry, it's ReadLines. I've corrected this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that all involved computers are with `.net 4.0` installed?
And that Powershell is version `3.0` or at least `2.0` with powershell.exe.config customized to use .Net 4.0 ?

`File.ReadLines` starts only from .Net 4.0.

Why not use `get-content` cmdlet?

Comment: My solution with ReadLines works fine on my pc (Windows 8), another pc has installed Windows7.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a strong reason to use `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines`, consider PowerShell's `Get-Content` cmdlet instead:

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content .\my\file.txt)
{
   Write-Output $line
}
```

Also, `foreach` is an alias for `ForEach-Object` and you can pipe to it. Each object in the pipeline is referred to as $_. So you can write a script block which will run for every line in your file like this:

```
Get-Content .\my\file.txt | { Write-Output $_ }
```